# Change the CSS for every different languages that are divided by the views scope

Tags: magento-1.7, language

I have a menu generated by Magento category. And every link is an image. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like (it's in french):

[image: Image menu]

I was wandering how can I code my CSS so that when it's another language the background-image changes?

I though there was way to define a class or id when creating a category but I did not see anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the template you could assign a class name to necessary elements based on:

```
$code = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
```

So you might end up with something such as:

```
<?php $code = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() ?>
<div class="menu <?php echo $code ?>-image">
    <!-- Your menu stuff -->
</div>
```

And then you can simply assign correct images in your CSS:

```
.fr_FR-image { background: url('fr-image.png'); }
.en_US-image { background: url('en-image.png'); }
```

If you'd prefer, you could build a simple helper to assign a more desirable class name using `strtolower()` and/or `str_replace()` as potential suggestions (or just do it all in your template, but that can be sloppy). Something like:

```
<?php $code = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() ?>
<?php $class = strtolower(str_replace('_', '-', $code)) ?>
<?php // fr-fr-image, en-us-image, etc ?>
```

Alternatively, depending on how you have your CSS scoped, you may want to simply add the locale code to the `<body>` element (using above method), that way you will be able to scope any locale specific CSS based on that. You'd end up with something like:

```
<body class="cms-index-index cms-home fr-fr">
```

And the CSS could follow:

```
.fr-fr .my-menu-image { background: url('fr-image.png'); }
.en-en .my-menu-image { background: url('en-image.png'); }
```

Comment: Precisely the answer I was formulating. Great work.